# My Ionic page is not loading, rendering, and my app is doing nothing when I press the sidemenu link

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I an making an app using Ionic and AngularJS. I made a page, but when I put this HTML on it it does not load to anything other than a blank screen. When I click on the navigation link in the sidemenu, nothing happens, and Ionic does not even try to load the page. I am probably missing something obvious, but help would be appreciated. Here is my ion-content:

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Happiness</ion-label>
      <ion-range value="100">
        <ion-label slot="start"></ion-label>
        <ion-icon slot="end"></ion-icon>
      </ion-range>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Fear</ion-label>
      <ion-range value="100">
        <ion-label slot="start"></ion-label>
        <ion-icon slot="end"></ion-icon>
      </ion-range>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Anger</ion-label>
      <ion-range value="100">
        <ion-label slot="start"></ion-label>
        <ion-icon slot="end"></ion-icon>
      </ion-range>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Stress</ion-label>
      <ion-range value="100">
        <ion-label slot="start"></ion-label>
        <ion-icon slot="end"></ion-icon>
      </ion-range>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Energy</ion-label>
    <ion-range value="100">
      <ion-label slot="start"></ion-label>
      <ion-icon slot="end">⚡</ion-icon>
    </ion-range>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Worry</ion-label>
      <ion-range value="100">
        <ion-label slot="start"></ion-label>
        <ion-icon slot="end"></ion-icon>
      </ion-range>
  </ion-item>
<ion-list>
<ion-button color="primary">Save</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing here in your html example that could cause app to no respond, this could be duo to routing or duo to typescript page wrong or bad code which is causing app to not continue its normal load.

Comment: @MostafaHarb when I comment everything out and just add a <p> it works. I tried deleting then ionic g page-ing andi it didn't work.

Comment: Put only one item in the ion list,and remove its entire elements in the ion-range

Comment: <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Energy</ion-label>
    <ion-range value="100">
          </ion-range>
  </ion-item>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ion-list tag is not closed. Missed a / there.